# Play Store: App has been removed for violating Location permission policy

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-developer-api, titanium-android, titanium-sdk

Our app has been removed from the play store due to the violation of the location permission policy. According to their rejection mail, we have been using the user's background location but actually, in our app, we only use the user's location only while using the app. We have added these two API permissions(`access_coarse_location,access_fine_location`) explicitly in our manifest file which is used only for foreground location access. So we have re-submit the app again and again but the app got rejected for the same reason.

Also, we have declared in the location permission policy form that we don’t access user location in the background and attached a demo video link as well.

We also made an appeal a few days back but did not get any information on that so far. Our business has been impacted a lot because of this inconvenience.

Details:

```
Ti SDK: 9.0.3.GA
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="30"/>
```

App Manifest:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Your help will be appreciated!!! Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about app store policies are off topic here.  The only one who can answer them is Google.

Comment: Which release tracks are those APK versions on? Keep in mind that if you have any old APKs on the alpha/beta/internal test tracks that use background location (or that use foreground location but has a `targetSdkVersion` of 28 or less), then you must update those tracks as well.

Comment: @GabeSechan I understand your concern but the google play store has not given info on this. Therefore I have put this question to this forum might be other developers has faced this issue. Hoping  a lead from here.

Comment: You appear to be using [Titanium SDK which is a EOL/deprecated product](https://blog.axway.com/mobile-apps/changes-to-application-development-services). I would seriously look to migrating off that platform as it may be using background techniques no longer allowed by Google Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue coming because you are getting user location in background task like async task, handler and others sources. Please get location in foreground. After that resubmit the in play store.